# How to integrate Kendo UI datawiz onto a page without having to refresh it

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Datawiz bar charts to represent some information which i have collected through input boxes and saved into an array. I want to beable to display the bar chart after the data has been submitted on the same page. however the code for the bar chart is in a separate html file than the page i want to display it on. When i integrated the two html files, things messed up so is there a way to display the chart even though the code is in a different html file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an iframe?

```
<form target="iframe" action="chart.html">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" width=100% src="chart.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: yeah, that was one of the options i tried. But i discovered that Kendoui has an api to redraw the graph on the page which i used instead.